# MS Access to MS Access data transfer without overwriting

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

Quick question, assuming that I have two access databases with tables that have exactly the same headers, how would I go about appending data from DATABASE1_TABLE_A to DATABASE2_TABLE_B using VBA (executed from DATABASE1). I tried the

```
DoCmd.CopyObject "DATABASE2_DESTINATION", "TABLE_B", acTable, "TABLE_A"
```

which works, however it overwrites existing DATABASE2_TABLE_B rather than appending data to it. Is there another command which allows appending data from one access database to the other without overwriting existing data?

In theory I could complete

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "Microsoft Access", DATABASE2_DESTINATION", acTable, "TABLE_B", "RANDOM_DB_NAME", False
```

Then merge my table with the table transfered and then execute DoCmd.CopyObject but it seems like it's a very inefficienc method to go about this problem.

V/R

Comment: Why don't you use an SQL statement like `INSERT INTO tblDest IN 'DB.accdb'
SELECT tblSource.*
FROM tblSource;`

Comment: Tbh I didn't know that option existed. I was fully convinced that creating connection between two databases in order to execute SQL. Do you by chance have any good resource on utilizing SQL between two separate database files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two tables with the same structure you could use the following code to do the job

```
Sub copyData()

    Dim db As database  ' add reference to DAO library
    Set db = CurrentDb

    Dim sSQL As String
    Dim dbName As String
    dbName = "Path\TargetDB.accdb"

    sSQL = "INSERT INTO tblDest IN '" & _
        dbName & _
        "'SELECT tblData.* FROM tblData;"

    db.Execute sSQL

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thank you for opening my eyes to the new skillset that I never knew I needed. For whatever reason I thought that in order to execute SQL queries between two files, I'd have to create ODBC connection and/or install Microsoft Access Database Engine. Do you by chance have any good reference regarding utilizing SQL with MS Access? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Maybe this [one](https://codekabinett.com/rdumps.php?Lang=2&targetDoc=vba-sql-string-tutorial) helps. [Here](https://www.fmsinc.com/free/tips.html) you also find a lot of good articles and tips regarding  Access